# Update shopping cart object inside Meteor user profile

Tags: javascript, mongodb, meteor

I'm trying to delete from shopping cart, and change quantity information in user profile: here is the structure:

```
    {
      "_id": "3YmDfDWMAaoeQHPAJ",
      "profile": {
        "name": "Armin",
        "wish": [
          "FMXRAn3TEXCn6skSX",
          "avRwogpGvJsKLLKfK",
          "PJbRh68pwJrtnKe5c",
          "mt2yqLecyTA2Ejd4n"
        ],
        "cart": {
          "mt2yqLecyTA2Ejd4n": "1",
          "xqwfyqasfcyTA2ajd": "3",
          "xL438DBQrNJTJbPmH": "5"
        }
      },
      "username": "armin"
    }
```

I tried the following but it will delete the whole cart

```
    let item = $(event.target).data('id');
    Meteor.users.update(Meteor.userId(),{$unset: {"profile.cart": item}});
```

My goal is to be able to update the value 1,3,5 . and also be able to delete a whole property from cart.

Comment: You can delete a property in javascript using the `delete [PropertyName]` ; using the `delete` keyword

Comment: i tried 
`delete Meteor.user().profile.cart[item] `
 but it dosnt work in meteor i guess.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To update an attribute's value in the cart, use [$set](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/set/) operator like in the following query:

```
Meteor.users.update(
    Meteor.userId(),
    {$set: {"profile.cart.xL438DBQrNJTJbPmH": "10"}}
);
```

To delete an attribute in the cart:

```
Meteor.users.update(
    Meteor.userId(), 
    {$unset: {"profile.cart.xL438DBQrNJTJbPmH": ""}}
);
```

The specified value in the $unset expression (i.e. "") does not impact the operation.

In the case when you have to construct the attribute's name dynamically, you can use an additional variable:

```
var condition = {}; 
condition["profile.cart." + dynamicPart] = "";
Meteor.users.update(
    Meteor.userId(), 
    {$unset: condition}
);
```

Comment: it worked fine when i used the exact `"profile.cart.xL438DBQrNJTJbPmH"` .the problem is i need to attach the id like this `newItem = "profile.cart."+receivedId` then use it '{$unset: {newItem : ""}} 
in this case i get a Access denied console log.

Comment: update : i think it worked by adding [] around receivedId.